# What does "CI=false npm run build" mean to not treat warnings as errors on Netlify or Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, netlify, vercel

Netlify and Vercel both would refuse to deploy if there is a tiny warning, with the error message:

```
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
```

and so the solution is:

[How to prevent Netlify from treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415804/how-to-prevent-netlify-from-treating-warnings-as-errors-because-process-env-ci/62490508#62490508)

override the build command with:

```
CI=false npm run build
```

or

```
CI= npm run build
```

what do they mean?  Aren't they just setting the environment variable `CI` and not really a "command"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strange variable definition in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195544/strange-variable-definition-in-shell-script)

Comment: or CI='' npm run build

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true. Failed to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663451/treating-warnings-as-errors-because-process-env-ci-true-failed-to-compile)

Answer (score 3):

Just like the usage of

```
GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep foo bar.txt
```

so

```
CI=false npm run build
```

is to mean, set the environment variable `CI` to `false` and then under such condition, run the command `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you use webpack like me, you need add commands above.
I hope that will be solution of your problems :)